# Output an array with a function in it

Tags: javascript, html

so i want to make a piece of code that starts with a set of variables, then uses .sort() and .length() to order then alphabetically and number then, then output the result, any ideas? i have come up with this so far but it only outputs the contents under

`

```
<h1>task 2</h1>

<script>
var products ["Router","Tablet","Printer","Nachos","sandwhich"];
document.write(products.sort());
document.write(prod caucts.length);
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
var products=["Router","Tablet","Printer","Nachos","sandwhich"];
products.sort();
var enumerated_products=[];
products.forEach(function(x,i,arr){enumerated_products.push({x,i})});
console.log(enumerated_products);
</script>
```